# Is it possible to develop in Windows and then generate app in Mac with Cordova/PhoneGap or Sencha Touch

Tags: ios, extjs, cordova, sencha-touch

I need to develop an iOS app, but with the magic of Cordova/PhoneGap or Sencha Touch, I am thinking whether it is possible that :

Can I do development in Windows and when the whole project is finished then I copy the entire source code onto Mac and use the Cordova/PhoneGap or Sencha Touch to generate the iOS app?

I am sure if the approach works, it will benefit many windows developers about developing their iOS apps.

Comment: well, you can use whatever platform you want to develop your application. Only issue is compilation: iOS app can be only compiled in Mac

Comment: @Lixas, Hi that's the reason why I am asking this question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your app using the windows platform, but you will need a mac to compile it into an ios app.

Good news is if you're using the Cordova CLI then you simply need to use one line of code to create an ios app out of it "cordova platform add ios" ... but this has to be done using a mac. There is no other way to do this without a mac.

Goodluck!